# Why increasing number of workers (more than number of cores) still decrease execution time?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I always sure that there is no point to have more threads/processes than CPU cores (from the performance perspective). However, my python sample shows me a different result.

```
import concurrent.futures
import random
import time


def doSomething(task_num):
    print("executing...", task_num)
    time.sleep(1)  # simulate heavy operation that takes ~ 1 second    
    return random.randint(1, 10) * random.randint(1, 500)  # real operation, used random to avoid caches and so on...


def main():
    # This part is not taken in consideration because I don't want to
    # measure the worker creation time
    executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=60)

    start_time = time.time()

    for i in range(1, 100): # execute 100 tasks
        executor.map(doSomething, [i, ])
    executor.shutdown(wait=True)

    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Program results:

> 1 WORKER  --- 100.28233647346497 seconds ---
>   2 WORKERS --- 50.26122164726257 seconds ---
>   3 WORKERS --- 33.32741022109985 seconds ---
>   4 WORKERS --- 25.399883031845093 seconds ---
>   5 WORKERS --- 20.434186220169067 seconds ---
>   10 WORKERS--- 10.903695344924927 seconds ---
>   50 WORKERS--- 6.363946914672852 seconds ---
>   60 WORKERS--- 4.819359302520752 seconds ---

**How this can work faster having just 4 Logical processors ?**

Here is my Computer specifications (Tested on Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14):

> CPU Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz 
>    Sockets: 1 
>    Cores:   2
>    **Logical processors:    4**

Comment: `time.sleep(1)` doesn't block the CPU. In the time one worker is sleeping, the others can use the CPU.

I suspect if you used an active wait you'd see the expected result.

Comment: indeed, the unexpected behavior where caused by sleep. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is because `sleep()` only uses a negligible amount of CPU. In this case, it is a poor simulation of actual work performed by a thread.

All `sleep()` really does is suspend the thread until the timer expires. While the thread is suspended, it doesn't use any CPU cycles.

Answer (score 2):

I extended your example with a more intensive computation (eg. matrix inversion). You will see what you expected: the computation time will decrease to the number of cores and increase afterwards (because of the cost of context switching).

```
import concurrent.futures
import random
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def doSomething(task_num):
    print("executing...", task_num)
    for i in range(100000):
        A = np.random.normal(0,1,(1000,1000))
        B = np.inv(A)

    return random.randint(1, 10) * random.randint(1, 500)  # real operation, used random to avoid caches and so on...

def measureTime(nWorkers: int):
    executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=nWorkers)
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(1, 40):  # execute 100 tasks
        executor.map(doSomething, [i, ])
    executor.shutdown(wait=True)
    return (time.time() - start_time)

def main():
    # This part is not taken in consideration because I don't want to
    # measure the worker creation time
    maxWorkers = 20
    dT = np.zeros(maxWorkers)
    for i in range(maxWorkers):
        dT[i] = measureTime(i+1)
        print("--- %s seconds ---" % dT[i])
    plt.plot(np.linspace(1,maxWorkers, maxWorkers), dT)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```